# C# editing and adding function to nested class of abstract class

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine

I have the abstract class shown below. It's nested class B is where I would like to define new functions.

```
public abstract class A {
    public string varA = "Default";
    public class B {
        public B() {

        }
        public abstract somethingCool(int[] val);
    }
}

public class C:A {
    //set B functions
}
```

Comment: What is your question? And why isn't class B abstract when it has an abstract member?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you NEED B to be a nested class? Why not just let your A class have a property of type B? Also, the somethingCool method needs a return type.

```
public abstract class A 
{
    public string varA = "Default";
    public B InstanceOfB { get; set; }
}

public abstract class B 
{
    public abstract void SomethingCool(int[] val);
}

public class C : A
{
    public override void SomethingCool(int[] val)
    { 
        //do something cool 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to implement B's functions from C, then mark B as abstract and subclass it in C. You can then override the abstract somethingCool method. Something like this:

```
public abstract class A
{
   public string varA = "Default";
   public abstract class B
   {
      public B() {}
      public abstract void somethingCool(int[] val);
   }

   public void Foo(B bar, int[] val)
   {
      bar.somethingCool(val);
   }
}

public class C : A
{
   // set B functions
   public class D : A.B
   {
      public override void somethingCool(int[] val)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < val.Length; ++i)
         {
            System.Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", val[i]));
         }         
      }
   }
}
```

Note that you can also subclass B from outside C:

```
public class E : A.B
{
   public override void somethingCool(int[] val)
   {
      for (int i = val.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
      {
         System.Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", val[i]));
      }
   }
}
```

Results:

```
public class Test
{
   public void Test()
   {
      int[] val = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

      var C = new C();
      var D = new C.D();
      C.Foo(D, val); // should print 1 2 3

      var E = new E();
      C.Foo(E, val); // should print 3 2 1
   }
}
```